# regex how to filter this list?

Tags: regex

i use word list updater 2.7 for windows to filetr this type of list:

```
      <username>vasile_2200</username> 
      <user_password>2550e911cb740fbfc8b08482bc6b80a5</user_password> 
  </item>

- <item>
      <username>spitalfetesti</username> 
      <user_password>e28e9b2242e579f40bc78d08628c7297</user_password> 
  </item>
- <item>
      <username>spital_bailesti</username> 
      <user_password>62a12df86a9bf85fc77fe495783f79fd</user_password> 
  </item>
```

filter only hashes

62a12df86a9bf85fc77fe495783f79fd

Comment: maybe this `<user_password>([^<]*)<\/user_password>`?

Comment: not working .............

Comment: @MunteanCosminManim show us what you're using to filter. Nikos' solution should've worked.

Comment: is working now, he modify ........